# Java 8: Do not understand the way Java implements Functional Interfaces

Tags: java, methods, lambda, method-reference

lets say we a `Predicate` and a `Function`-Interface:

```
Function<String, String> function = null;
Predicate<String> predicate = null;
```

Now I want to give the `Predicate`-Interface a method reference where the return type is a `boolean` and in our case the parameter a string. But why the following method reference seems to be right:

```
Predicate<String> predicate = String::isEmpty;
```

The `isEmpty`-method has no String-Parameter,although the `Predicate`-Interface requires a String-Parameter. Why it is still right? Am I missing something?

Another Example: The Function interface returns in our case a String and takes a String as parameter. But the following method reference seems to be wrong:

```
Function<String, String> function = String::concat;  //wrong
```

The Concat-Method has a String as Parameter and returns a String. Why its wrong?

Hopefully somebody can explain it to me.

Comment: Your question is really about method references rather than functional interfaces. I recommend you read through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html It explains the four types of method references and the lambda expressions they are shorthands for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a method reference on an instance method, the method receiver becomes the first argument.  So

```
String::isEmpty
```

is equivalent to

```
(String str) -> str.isEmpty()
```

and

```
String::concat
```

is equivalent to

```
(String a, String b) -> a.concat(b)
```

...which does not match the type of `Function`.

Comment: For completeness it might be worth adding an example of a reference to an instance method of a particular object. For example `myString::concat` is equivalent to `(String a) -> myString.concat(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why

```
Function<String, String> function = String::concat;
```

does not compile is because it is equivalent to (as Louis written)

```
Function<String, String> function = (String a, String b) -> a.concat(b);
```

while `Function.apply(T t)` takes only one argument (`t`) and you are passing a function that takes two arguments (`a` and `b`).

Answer (score 0):

`String::isEmpty` can, in theory, mean one of two things.

1. A static method in the String class:

   ```
   s -> String.isEmpty(s)
   ```
2. An instance method in the String class:

   ```
   (String s) -> s.isEmpty()
   ```

Your case falls into #2.

Similarly, `String::concat` can mean one of two things:

```
    (s1, s2) -> String.concat(s1, s2)
```

or

```
    (String s1, String s2) -> s1.concat(s2) // Your case
```

(However, this is not a `Function<String, String>`, as it does not take precisely one argument.  It is, however, a `BinaryOperator<String>`.)